# Ocultar div haciendo click en cualquier parte de la página

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un **div** que lo muestro y oculto con la función **toggle()**.
Quisiera que una vez desplegado haciendo click en cualquier parte de la página se oculte de nuevo sin tener que hacer click en ese div otra vez.

Muchas gracias.

```
function inicio(){
$("#idioma-nav").click(desplegarMenuIdioma);
```

}

```
function desplegarMenuIdioma(){
$("#menu-idioma-nav").toggle();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas

te dejo el CodePen por si quieres editarlo o verlo mejor

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/lusaxweb/pen/YEjvVK?editors=1111)

Bueno la idea principal es cuando se abre el modal agregarle una clase al `body` y cuando se ejecute el evento `click` quitársela

```js
$(document).on("click",".cerrarModal",function(){
  $(".modal").fadeOut();
  $(".cerrarModal").attr("class","")  
})

$("#abrirmodal").click(function(){
  $(".modal").fadeIn();
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("body").addClass("cerrarModal");
  }, 10);
  })
```

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(50, 34, 68);
}
.modal {
  padding: 30px;
  background: rgb(85, 156, 1);
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="abrirmodal" type="button" name="button">Abrir modal</button>

<div class="modal">
  hola modal
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, tu aporte me ha servido de mucho. Saludos!!!!

Comment: Si soluciona tu problema por favor dale como respuesta correcta para que la comunidad sepa saludos y que bueno poder ayudarte amigo

Comment: Disculpa, ya está. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
 var m = document.getElementById("modal");
 if(m.style.display !== "none") (function (){
 window.addEventListener("click", () => { m.style.display = "none";
 console.log("El modal desapareció al dar CLICK !")
 });
 })();
});
```

```html
<h6 id="modal">Soy un modal</h6>
```